# nginx trouble loading index file

Tags: php, nginx

I have this vhost conf

```conf
server { # php/fastcgi
    listen       80;
    server_name  trinityplex.com www.trinity.com;
    error_log   /home/web/trinity_web/log/error.log;
    access_log   /home/web/trinity_web/log/access.log;
    root /home/web/trinity_web/public;

    location / {
      index    index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

When I restart nginx it dumps

> Starting nginx: 2011/04/16 18:56:34 [emerg] 2492#0: invalid number of arguments in "fastcgi_pass" directive in /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/trinityplex.com:14

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe the missing ; after fastcgi_pass?

Comment: oh god, really embarrassing, fixed.
But it gives me 502 Bad gateway and error log specified in conf is empty. Have other ideas?

Comment: In this case check that php-fpm is actually running at the location that you specified under `fastcgi_pass` (`127.0.0.1:9000` in your case).
(Wrote this reply for others that might run into the same issue)